# multi-touch gestures on Thinkpad T61

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch

I'm currently running elementaryOS Freya on my Thinkpad T61 and want to use multi-touch gestures. Out of the box I can use 2-finger swipes for scrolling (although it works rather badly with this OS).

```
$ grep "TouchPad: buttons:" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

gives me this output:

```
(--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right middle double triple
```

so my touchpad is definitely capable of 3-finger gestures. However, I've tried for days now to get touchegg, ginn or xSwipe to work but when I enter the test-mode via `touchegg` or `ginn` in the terminal, it doesn't register any input at all, not even a simple tap.

Possible solutions that I've already tried include:

deactivating all native gestures in the synaptics driver

```
$ synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
$ synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0 
$ synclient TapButton1=0
$ synclient TapButton2=0
$ synclient TapButton3=0
$ synclient ClickFinger1=0
$ synclient ClickFinger2=0
$ synclient ClickFinger3=0
$ synclient PalmDetect=0
$ synclient GrabEventDevice=0
```

using evdev driver instead of synaptics (in /etc/X11/xorg.conf as well as /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf)

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "evdev touchpad catchall"
  Driver "evdev"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Option "Protocol" "event"
  Option "SHMConfig" "on"
EndSection
```

and downgrading to an older version of the synaptics driver as recommended in the installation instructions for xSwipe

```
$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libevdev-dev 
$ autoconf automake libmtdev-dev xorg-dev xutils-dev libtool git libx11-guitest-perl
$ git clone https://github.com/felipejfc/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.git 
$ cd xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/ 
$ ./autogen.sh 
$ ./configure --exec_prefix=/usr 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I also installed touchegg in a xubuntu live environment to rule out incompatibility with elementaryOS.